# Application.Run() is working while debugging In Windows Service, but after installing the service , it is not working

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to write the keylogger in windows services. so that i had used Application.Run() method

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

           Application.Run();

        }
```

i try to install the service using installutil.exe command prompt, the it is showing as :

```
The transacted install has completed.
The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed.
```

if i remove Application.Run(), the it is installing but the keylogging is not working.
Any alternate to Application.Run() that calls the method

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{

}
```

please help me to find out how to run with Application.Run() or any other alternate to Application.Run() to call the function HookCallBack

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how a service does work. The service itself is just a wrapper for the service controller from windows where start/stop/pause and other service related operating system commands are handled.

You would need to create a thread inside the service which does execute your application logic. Afterwards there should be no problem.

Please note, that I doubt that you can achieve your target by using a windows service. A windows service has by default desktop interaction disabled due to security. For accessing the desktop or any other related UI stuff you would need to change the security settings of the service with the checkbox 'Allow service to interact with desktop' (But I cannot tell you if this will work for you, as in that you really can inspect keys entered by the user).

Please also check out this [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications).